# Sort arrays inside object based on value inside each array

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JavaScript object:

```
 var javascriptObj = response[Object.keys(response)[Object.keys(response).length - 1]]
```

which looks like this:

```
  [["1", 121], ["10", 58], ["2", 69], ["3", 246], ["4", 3], ["5", 446], ["6", 124], ["7", 396], ["8", 190], ["9", 46]]
```

Is there a way to convert the values ("1","2","3") into integer and then sort the object based on this number?

**EDITED**

The values don't always stay the same. Some times it is from 1 to 5 or 8-13. And also it can be that there are missing values in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var javascriptObj = [["1", 121], ["10", 58], ["2", 69], ["3", 246], ["4", 3], ["5", 446], ["6", 124], ["7", 396], ["8", 190], ["9", 46]];

var output = javascriptObj.map(function(array) {
   return [+array[0], array[1]];
}).sort(function(a, b) {
   return a[0]-b[0];
});
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this ...

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {return parseInt(a[0], 10) - parseInt(b[0], 10)});
```

**UPDATE**: Changed a[1] and b[1] to a[0] and b[0].

Comment: it should be a[0] and b[0]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a[0]` and `b[0]`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The values don't always stay the same. Some times it is from 1 to 5 or 8-13. And also it can be that there are missing values in between.

Comment: @dkar: I think you should update your question with whatever you have commented above so that other people can read them before solving.